# StructuredStreaming - processing data based on new events in Kafka topic

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, spark-structured-streaming

I have a structured Streaming program, which read data from Kafka topic A, and does some processing, and finally puts data into target Kafka Topic.

Note :
the processing is done in function - convertToDictForEachBatch(), which called using - foreachBatch(convertToDictForEachBatch)

As part of the processing, it reads another Kafka Topic (events_topic), and if there is a New record(s) after the last read,
it does some additional processing - reloads data from BigQuery table, and persists it.

```
df_stream = spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", ssl_truststore_location) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", ssl_truststore_password) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", ssl_keystore_password) \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaBrokers)\
        .option("subscribe", topic) \
        .option("kafka.group.id", consumerGroupId)\
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10000) \
        .load()


    print(" df_stream -> ", df_stream)
    query = df_stream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp").writeStream \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .trigger(processingTime='4 minutes') \
        .option("numRows",10000)\
        .option("truncate", "false") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint) \
        .foreachBatch(convertToDictForEachBatch) \
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

```
# called from - foreachbatch
def convertToDictForEachBatch(df, batchId):
      
    # Uses the dataframe to do processing of data, the code is not added, since it is not relevant to this question 

   # Additional processing i.e. reloading of prediction data from Big query, into Data Frame - based on event in Kafka topic   
   # checks for event in topic - topic_reloadpred and further processing takes place if there is new data in the topic
    events = spark.read.format('kafka') \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers) \
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", ssl_truststore_location) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", ssl_truststore_password) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location_reloadpred) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", ssl_keystore_password_reloadpred) \
        .option("subscribe", topic_reloadpred) \
        .option("kafka.group.id", consumerGroupId_reloadpred) \
        .load()

    # events is passed to a function, and processing is done if new events are generated
```

What is the best way to achieve this ?
The current code is reading the entire data in the kafka topic, i need it to read only the new data.

Comment: I don't think this will work. More specifically, you're not actually checking if the incoming dataframe has any data in it... If you want to join different topics based on overlapping events, you'll need to introduce windowing, rather than start a batch consumer for every streaming event

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. However, if you simply want to avoid reading entire data from events_topic and read only new events, you need to maintain offsets that you have read so far. You can provide starting offset as the offset that you read last time and ending offset as latest. Link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries

Comment: @RishabhSharma - yes, the requirement is to avoid reading all the data from event_topic and read only new events. As you mentioned, i can use startingOffset to specify the last-read-offset+1, where do i store the last-read-offset ? I'm using GCP, so can possibly use StorageBucket (instead of another Kafka topic) ?

Comment: Or possibly use df.persist or broadcast ?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - i've updated the description so the requirement is clear(er). The DF in function is used to do processing, that code is not included. Additional processing (refreshing DF with data from Bigquery) is done based on event in topic 'topic_reloadpred'. There is no join being done, only the data re-loaded from BigQuery based on new event in Kafka topic

Comment: @KaranAlang You can store your offsets anywhere literally - db, zk, file. You just need to ensure that offset update happens post successful processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Rishabh Sharma, i'm storing the offset in a separate kafka topic which has a single partition(i could store it in separate partition in the same topic as well).
During processing, i'm checking the last updated offset against the current offset added. If the current offset is more than the last updated offset, i do further processing (i.e. reload the table from BigQuery)